# How to profile only a class library?

Tags: c#, dll, profiling, visual-studio-2012

I want to profile the CPU usage of a class library project which is compiled into a dll with VS2012.

When I go into Analyze -> Launch Performance Wizard, I can choose which project to profile but it only lets me profile executables, so I can't profile my library.

If I profile both of my projects (one is a very simple Form which runs functions from my library and shows some output) then `System.Windows.Forms.Application.Run` takes up 97% of my samples - I don't really care about the performance cost of the form, and it overwhelms everything else.

How can I see the performance data for just my dll?

Comment: This is at least one reason that unit tests are useful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to create a unit test which exercises the various library functions you are interested in profiling.

You can then right click on the test in the "Test Explorer" and then select "Profile Test".

[image: Screenshot]

This should kick off a performance analysis session for the selected test. I not sure why they hid this very useful feature so well!

In VS2012, this option may be grayed out. In this case you can enable it by deleting your `%localappdata%\Microsoft\VisualStudio\11.0\ComponentModelCache` folder and restarting Visual Studio. ([source](http://www.hjerpbakk.com/blog/2013/7/11/enable-profile-test-in-visual-studio-2012s-test-explorer-1.html))

Comment: Thank you for answering after so long! I had no idea about this feature, I'll try it out when I have the chance.

Comment: No problem, I didn't notice the date this was posted!